# Rust: "wrapping" an iterator

Tags: rust

Does anyone know if Rust provide some sort of wrapping iterators? For example:

```
let data = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
let mut it = data.into_iter();
let mut wrapped = some_wrapping_iter(it); // wrap it

wrapped.take(2).for_each(|e| process_first_2_elems(e));

it = wrapped.into(); // and get back the original
it.for_each(|e| process_remaining(e));
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e097be649ee5941135978372b703036)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) helper method can be used to accomplish this.  This method forces borrowing the iterator instead of consuming it, which works because there is a blanket implementation in the standard library [`impl<I> Iterator for &mut I where I: Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-for-%26mut+I).

```
let data = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
let mut it = data.into_iter();

it.by_ref().take(2).for_each(|e| process_first_2_elems(e));
it.for_each(|e| process_remaining(e));
```

You could also accomplish this by taking an exclusive reference yourself (`by_ref` only makes it more ergonomic -- under the hood it is just taking a reference):

```
(&mut it).take(2).for_each(|e| process_first_2_elems(e));
```

Comment: Wow, that is cool, didn't know that usage.